# Event Conflict between Parent Draggable and Child Input type Range

Tags: javascript

I am trying to perform a drag operation on a div that contains a child input type "range" element, but since its parent div has drag event registered, I am unable to slide the range element in FIREFOX but it works in chrome (WHY?..Please do tell this too..). Please suggest a solution.

http://jsbin.com/ASabAFuw/8/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a browser bug, the slider doesn't even receive `dragstart` event in Firefox. If it did, you'd be able to prevent bubbling.

But you can block drag and drop by returning false from `dragstart` handler if the active element is an input (maybe you also need to check for links or textareas):

```
function dragStartCallback(event) {
  if (document.activeElement.tagName == 'INPUT') {
      return false; // block dragging
  }
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text', ' Dropped')
}
```

There's also another issue: `onSliderChange` calls `event.preventDefault()`, so when you release the mouse button the slider continues to move in Chrome, and reverts to the previous position in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, bubbling could have been prevented in that case. I have now commented event.preventDefault() in onSliderChange() also and added document.activeElement.tagName == 'INPUT' and it works now. Thanks Alexey.

Comment: active element always appears to be body

Comment: As I was handling this event in subsequent function additional `event.preventDefault()` finally solved it. Thanks!