# Disable HTML5 Drag & Drop for Range Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way of disabling HTML5 drag and drop on a specific element inside a draggable element?

In my case we are building a list of items that all have settings, we want to be able to use `<input type="range" />` inside of it. But whenever the user tries to drag the handle of the correctly rendered range input the whole draggable item starts its dragging cycle of events.

I have tried capturing the event in the range input to prevent default on it. But the `dragstart` event is not triggered on it.

The markup is roughly structured like this:

```
<div class="item_wrapper" draggable="true">
  <div class="field-group param_percent">
    <label for="param_card">Darken</label>
    <div class="parameter" data-default="0" data-value="">
      <input type="range" id="param_card_range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See the working answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818291/event-conflict-between-parent-draggable-and-child-input-type-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening to the `dragstart` event does nothing unless you actually enable the drag and drop features on the element where you want to handle the event. So I ended up adding the `draggable="true"` parameter to the input range. Then the `dragstart`event gets triggered.

The handler should then simply prevent default and stop the event propagation.

```
  /**
   * Handler for the drag start event. This is needed to prevent the dragging of
   * list items in the case that this parameter is used in such.
   * Simply stop everything.
   * @param e
   * @returns {boolean}
   * @private
   */
  _dragStart: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable element dragging on screen CSS like this.. 
https://gist.github.com/msuchodolski/41c9338f3a732379dc570142826ed76e

Here is working demo

```css
/**
 *   MAKE ELECTRON APP FEEL MORE NATIVE
 *
 *   * Prevent dragging all HTML elements, specially:
 *    - images
 *    - links (anchors)
 *
 *   * Prevent text selection
 */

*, *::after, *::before {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-drag: none;
 -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
 cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="item_wrapper" draggable="true">
  <div class="field-group param_percent">
    <label for="param_card">Darken</label>
    <div class="parameter" data-default="0" data-value="">
      <input type="range" id="param_card_range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! However it did not do the trick I'm afraid. I'm not doing Electron work, but this does not rely on that. However it does not work.

Comment: For me, when I run the code snippet in browser, it does not let me drag the element.. I can only drag the handle not element. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is what I need. But the solution you describe did not do the trick för me. I have found a working solution, will post it. Thanks for your input.